# Delaying screenshot from webcam with mplayer

Tags: linux, webcam, screenshot, mplayer

is there a way to delay screenshotting on mplayer?
The parameter "-ss" doesnt work, because its not a seekable input.

Currently im using:

```
mplayer -nosound tv:// -tv driver=v4l2:device=/dev/video1 -frames 2 -vf screenshot -vo png:z=9
```

but the first frame is empty (just green) - i think that comes from the initialization of the webcam. the second frame is ok

so my idea is, to skip the first 10 frames, and then take a screenshot, to be sure the camera is initialized every time.

what parameter should i use to get this result?

Answer (score 0):

It takes a while for some cams to initialize.  Have it take 2 shots and discard the 1st (vary the time between until it's sufficiently long enough to get a good 2nd shot)

Comment: yes, it sure comes from the initialization of the camera, as i mentioned before ;) Its possible to discard the first frame, yes, but i explicitly want to wait a second or 10 frames before i take the first screenshot